# label.text won't show the readline

Tags: vb.net, networking

I have to work with network program with vb 2010. I'm trying to show the ReadLine stream in label text but it won't show. Please help.

```
Dim tcpCli As TcpClient = tcpList.AcceptTcpClient() 'claiming tcp listener to accept the tcp client

Dim ns As NetworkStream = tcpCli.GetStream ' assign ns as network stream and assign as client to get nw stream
Dim sr As New StreamReader(ns)

''''''''' get data from client '''''''''''''''
Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim receivedData As String = sr.ReadLine()

MsgBox("Operation Performed!!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Accepted by client")
Form1.lblRreadStream.Text = receivedData.ToString() '<< this is the line i'm stuck in with.
```

Comment: please. i'm so much in need..

Comment: i put receivedData instead of "Operation Performed!!!". and it's still showing. the string is "Connected".
only the label won't show the string.

Comment: What is the length of 'receivedData'? (as from receivedData.Length)

Comment: i never define the length. o.o

Comment: you don't have to define it, it is set automatically. Add a second MsgBox: MsgBox("Length: " & receivedData.Length)

Comment: yep, it worked, length's 9, it showed.
only the label.text won't show.. 
:S

Comment: well.... np, i'd find a way out.. my first time network programming ain't gonna come easily.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on your problem line what does receivedData equal and after you step through it what does Form1.lblRreadStream.Text equal and just out of curiosity what is your label's Forecolor ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can do one of the following:

```
    Dim receivedData As String = sr.ReadLine()
    While (sr.ReadLine() <> Nothing)
        receivedData += sr.ReadLine()
    End While

    Form1.lblRreadStream.Text = receivedData
```

Or you could read the whole stream at once:

```
   Form1.lblRreadStream.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

Hope it helps